# RegEx to extract URL, target and link from custom markup

Tags: regex

I'm sure this is really simple, but I just can't figure it out.

I want to extract the URL, target and link from this

```
Example:
[http://www.testdomain.com/blog/122_Blog Post.aspx _blank]Click here![/]
```

I have tried this:

```
\[(.*) (.*)\](.+?)\[\/\]
```

It works as long as I have `_blank` or `_self` following the URL, but if I remove it all together, I get `Post.aspx` as target (of course).

I also tried things like `(_blank)?`, but that didn't work at all.

Please help, RegEx really isn't my thing, and feel free to suggest other improvements. It doesn't have to be foolproof, I just want to keep it simple.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more examples? What is in the place of `_blank` or `_self` in other cases?

Comment: There won't be many other cases that I can think of, other targets isn't really necessary. It's a closed system so I don't have to make it foolproof. As long as the URL can contain all possible characters, including whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\[(.*?)(?: (_blank|_self))?\](.+?)\[\/\]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\[(.*?) ?(_[\w\d]+)?\](.+?)\[\/\]
```

the first `(.*)` in your regex is greedy and need to be reluctant `(.*?)`

with regex there are greedy, reluctant and possessive qualifier. greedy is most common but some special cases need reluctant or possessive qualifiers.

check this link to test the regex
http://www.rubular.com/r/lszC0EWaWM

Comment: Voting up because of the explanation of greedy vs reluctant quantifiers.

Comment: This isn't working if the URL looks something like www.test.com/sub_folder. But thanks for the link!

Comment: @Cyrodor Yes the (_[\w\d]+)? part is not specific enough and should only match valid targets